# Find, with proof, a formula f(n) such that 1 − 2 + 3 − 4 + · · · + (−1)^(n−1)n = f(n) for all n ≥ 1.

Tags: logic, induction

Find, with proof, a formula f(n) such that $1 − 2 + 3 − 4 + · · · + (−1)^{n−1}n = f(n)$ for
all n ≥ 1. The formula f(n) will be defined in two pieces. One piece gives the value of
the sum when n is even, and the other piece gives the value of the sum when n is odd.

ok this is what i have so far...

formula for when n is odd: $f(n) = \frac{n+1}2$,
formula for when n is even: $f(n) = -\frac n2$

proof for when n is odd

Basis: when n = 1 we have f(n) = f(1) = 1 and $\frac{n+1}2 = 1+\frac12 = 1$. thus the statement is true when n = 1.

IH: assume that $f(i) = \frac{i + 1}2$ for i = 1,3,5,7,...,(2k-1) for some k >= 1

IS: We want to show that $f(k + 2) = \frac{(k + 2) + 1} 2 
$

this is where I'm having trouble. I not sure how to do the induction step in this scenario. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: Note that $f$ can be defined by $f(n+1)=f(n)+(-1)^n(n+1)$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: In the induction step, you don't want $f(k+2)$ but $f(2(k+1)-1)$.

Comment: Use MathJax please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k$ odd $f(k+2) = f(k) + (-1)^k(k+1) + (-1)^{k+1}(k+2)= f(k) - (k+1) + (k+2) = f(k) + 1$

You said $f(k) = \frac {k+1}2$ so $f(k+2) = f(k) + 1 = \frac {k+1}2 + 1 = \frac {(k+ 2) + 1}2$.

Now you don't actually have to prove both odd and even by induction.

Once you prove $f(n) = \frac {n+1}2$ for $n$ odd, then for $n$ even we have $f(n-1) = \frac {n-1+1}2 = \frac n2$ and $f(n) = f(n-1) + (-1)^{n-1} n = (\frac n2) - n = - \frac n2$.

Or if I had my druthers I'd prove $f(n) = -\frac n2$ for $n$ even first and then prove show that for $n$ odd $f(n-1) = -\frac {n-1}2$ and so $f(n) = f(n-1) + (-1)^{n-1}n = (-\frac {n-1}2) + n = \frac {n+1}2$.

....

If I were to prove fo $n$ even rather than be $n$ odd.  I'd do.

Base case: $n = 2$  $f(2) = 1-2 = -1 = -\frac {2}{2} = \frac {n}{2}$

Induction: if $f(n) = -\frac n2$ then $f(n+2) = f(n) + (n+1) - (n+2) = f(n) -1 = f(n) - \frac 22 = -\frac n2 - \frac 22 = -\frac {n+2}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different ways:

---

Let's look at $1-2+3-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n$

First let's do the following for n is even:
$$1-2+3-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n=(1-2)+(3-4)+(5\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n)=-1+(-1)+(-1)\cdots+(-1)$$ and you have $\frac n2$ times -1 so it is indeed $-\frac n2$

Now let's do the following for odd:
$$1-2+3-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n=1+(-2+3)+(-4+5)+(-6\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n)=1+1+\cdots+1$$ now, let's ignore the first 1, you have other than it $\frac{n-1}2$, and when adding the first +1 you get $\frac{n-1}2+1=\frac{n-1}2+\frac22=\frac{n-1+2}2=\frac{n+1}2$

---

With induction you can do the following:

For even, let's assume that $f(n)=-\frac n2$ so:$$f(n+2)=f(n)+n+1-(n+2)=f(n)-1=-\frac n2-1=-\frac n2-\frac 22=-\left(\frac {n}2+\frac n2\right)=-\frac {n+2}2$$ now let's check for n=2, $f(2)=1-2=-1=-\frac 22$ therefore don't n is even $-\frac n2$ is the formula

For n is odd let's assume that $f(n)=\frac{n+1}2$ so:$$f(n+2)=f(n)-(n+1)+n+2=f(n)+1=\frac{n+1}2+1=\frac{n+1}2+\frac22=\frac{n+1+2}2=\frac{(n+2)+1}2$$ let's check for n=1:$f(1)=1=\frac{1+1}2$ so the formula for n is odd is $\frac{n+1}2$

Comment: I'll quibble and say that a proof of "look at $1 - ......  +n= (1-2) + (3-4) + ..... ([n-1] - n)$"  *is* a proof by induction.  You are showing it holds for some case and will therefore hold for a general case.

Comment: @fleablood for my understanding induction is proofing for general case of $n+1$ using an assumption for $n$. But I don't think I know everything, if you are right, please can you send me to a source for better understanding induction?

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong, nor was I trying to say anything profound.  I doubt anyone has really written on the subject.  I'm just saying the "dot dot dot" method is an informal way of recognizing a pattern.  In one fell sweep it establishes a base case (the first term in the sequence) and a visual argument that the sequence is compelled to go forward and have a general result for any value.  In other words, it is a proof by induction presented visually.

Comment: @fleablood oh, okay. Thanks you for clarifying it

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:
$$f(2k+1)=f(2k)+2k+1$$
and 
$$f(2k)=f(2k-1)-2k$$
Add the above equations to get:
$$ f(2k+1)-f(2k-1)=1$$
Now add for $k$ ranging between $0$ and $n$ and obtain:
$$f(2n+1)-f(1)=n$$
Plug this expression into the first equation above to get:
$$f(2n)=-n$$